# Como elegir entre dos opciones en los parametros de un Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Muy buenas a todos compañeros.

Necesito crear un procedimiento que modifique automaticamente el campo de una tabla. Tiene que aceptar dos parametros

-Un caracter D o P segun corresponda la accion a realizar.

-un codigo de un libro tipo varchar (sin problema).

Nose como poner el primer parametro, como hacer que tenga esa opcion.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que hayas tratado o lleves al momento?

Comment: De momento no llevo nada, en el principio es donde tengo los problemas. Mis intentos son algo asi:                 ""CREATE PROCEDURE registrarcambios (IN operacion ('D','P), IN codigo mediumint(9))"" El problema lo tengo con el parametro operacion.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, pongo el codigo por si hay curiosidad:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE registrarcambios (IN operacion varchar(1), IN codigo mediumint(9))
 BEGIN
   IF operacion = 'D' then
      Update libros SET prestado ='N' where registro = codigo;
   ELSEIF operacion = 'P' then
      update libros SET prestado = 'S' WHERE registro = codigo;
   ELSE SELECT "Operacion solo puede ser D o P" AS mensaje;
   END IF;
END
```

Comment: Explicar tu código haría que tu aporte sea mejor recibido y además sea mas fácil de entender como construiste tu solución, checa [answer]